# Merging two lists into one and sorting the items

Tags: c#, sorting

Is there a way to merge(union without dupes) two given lists into one and store the items in sorted way by using ONE for loop?

Also, i am looking for a solution which does not makes use of API methods ( like, union, sort etc).

Sample Code.

```
private static void MergeAndOrder() 
{
var listOne = new List<int> {3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 6, 9, 11}; 
var listTwo = new List<int> {1, 7, 8, 3, 5, 10, 15, 12}; 

//Without Using C# helper methods...
//ToDo.............................

//Using C# APi.
var expectedResult = listOne.Union(listTwo).ToList(); 
expectedResult.Sort();//Output: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,15
//I need the same result without using API methods, and that too by iterating over items only once.


}
```

PS: I have been asked this question in an interview, but couldn't find answer as yet.

Comment: How are you going to access or manipulate the lists *in any way* if you can't use API methods?

Comment: I suspect the OP means not using methods like Union, Sort, etc to perform the core operation of the merge-and-sort.

Comment: Is a precondition that both lists are already sorted?  You say "one loop" so I assume you mean O(n) for the whole operation.  If they're not both already sorted, I'm not sure that's possible.

Comment: @Jonanthon, Both lists are unsorted.

Comment: If both lists are unsorted, then it is impossible to achieve O(n) performance.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms

Comment: Don't be dismayed by not knowing an answer for this question; unless you were interviewing for a job writing specialized sorting algorithms, it's a particularly irrelevant question to be asked to find out how good you are at solving *real* problems.

Comment: @Programming Hero - absolutely, and either the interviewer was deliberately asking unanswerable questions, they didn't know it was unanswerable, or they left out the essential "both lists presorted" condition.  Not so cool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without the precondition that both lists are sorted before the merge + sort operation, you can't do this in O(n) time (or "using one loop").

Add that precondition and the problem is very easy.

Keep two iterators, one for each list.  On each loop, compare the element from each list and choose the smaller.  Increment that list's iterator.  If the element you are about to insert in the final list is already the last element in that list, skip the insert.

In pseudocode:

```
List a = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }
List b = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 }
List result = { }
int i=0, j=0, lastIndex=0
while(i < a.length || j < b.length)
    // If we're done with a, just gobble up b (but don't add duplicates)
    if(i >= a.length)
        if(result[lastIndex] != b[j])
            result[++lastIndex] = b[j]
        j++
        continue

    // If we're done with b, just gobble up a (but don't add duplicates)
    if(j >= b.length)
        if(result[lastIndex] != a[i])
            result[++lastIndex] = a[i]
        i++
        continue

    int smallestVal

    // Choose the smaller of a or b
    if(a[i] < b[j])
        smallestVal = a[i++]
    else
        smallestVal = b[j++]

    // Don't insert duplicates
    if(result[lastIndex] != smallestVal)
        result[++lastIndex] = smallestVal
end while
```

Answer (score 12):

Why can't you use the api methods?  Re-inventing the wheel is dumb.  Also, it's the `.ToList()` call that's killing you.  *Never* call `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` until you absolutely have to, because they break your lazy evaluation.

Do it like this and you'll enumerate the lists with the minimum amount necessary:

```
var expectedResult = listOne.Union(listTwo).OrderBy(i => i);
```

This will do the union in one loop using a hashset, and lazy execution means the base-pass for the sort will piggyback on the union.  But I don't think it's possible finish the sort in a single iteration, because sorting is not a O(n) operation.

Comment: @Joel, 1. The intention is to break lazy evaliation, since the test code i want to show the output items.
2. We don't have 'Sort" method over IEnumerable, so i don;t think your line of code would compile.

Comment: @Amby Oops: that should be "OrderBy"  Fixed now.  And you still shouldn't call ToList().  You don't need to call ToList() to output the results.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static void MergeTwoSortedArray(int[] first, int[] second)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();

        int[] result = new int[first.Length + second.Length];

        int i=0 , j=0 , k=0;

        while(i < first.Length && j <second.Length)
        {
            if(first[i] < second[j])
            {
                result[k++] = first[i++];
            }
            else
            {
                result[k++] = second[j++];
            }
        }

        if (i < first.Length)
        {
            for (int a = i; a < first.Length; a++)
                result[k] = first[a];
        }

        if (j < second.Length)
        {
            for (int a = j; a < second.Length; a++)
                result[k++] = second[a];
        }

        foreach (int a in result)
            Console.Write(a + " ");

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using iterators and streaming interface the task is not that complicated:

class MergeTwoSortedLists
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

```
        var list1 = new List<int?>() {
            1,3,5,9,11
        };

        var list2 = new List<int?>() {
            2,5,6,11,15,17,19,29
        };

        foreach (var c in SortedAndMerged(list1.GetEnumerator(), list2.GetEnumerator())) {
            Console.Write(c+" ");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> SortedAndMerged(IEnumerator<int?> e1, IEnumerator<int?> e2) {
        e2.MoveNext();
        e1.MoveNext();

        do {
            while (e1.Current < e2.Current) {
                if (e1.Current != null) yield return e1.Current.Value;
                e1.MoveNext();
            }

            if (e2.Current != null) yield return e2.Current.Value;
            e2.MoveNext();
        } while (!(e1.Current == null && e2.Current == null));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
      public static IEnumerable<T> MergeWith<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection1, IEnumerable<T> collection2,
            IComparer<T> comparer)
        {
            using (var enumerator1 = collection1.GetEnumerator())
            using (var enumerator2 = collection2.GetEnumerator())
            {
                var isMoveNext1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
                var isMoveNext2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();

                do
                {
                    while (comparer.Compare(enumerator1.Current, enumerator2.Current) < 0 || !isMoveNext2)
                    {
                        if (isMoveNext1)
                            yield return enumerator1.Current;
                        else
                            break;

                        isMoveNext1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
                    }

                    if (isMoveNext2)
                        yield return enumerator2.Current;

                    isMoveNext2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
                } while (isMoveNext1 || isMoveNext2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Request you to explain your answer and also how your answer is better than already answers provided by others?

Comment: This is extension method for IEnumerable. You can use it in LINQ

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this, (I have considered numbers to be in arrays, but the overall logic doesn't differ).

```
int[] A = new int[] { 3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 6, 9, 11 };
int[] B = new int[] { 1, 7, 8, 3, 5, 10, 15, 12 };
int[] mainArr = MergeArrays(A, B);

int[] orderedArr = Sort(mainArr);
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(orderedArr[i]);

}

int[] MergeArrays(int[] arr1, int[] arr2)
{
    int total = arr1.Length + arr2.Length;
    int[] arr = new int[total];
    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        if (i >= arr1.Length)
        {
            arr.SetValue(arr2[i - arr1.Length], i);
        }
        else
        {
            arr.SetValue(arr1[i], i);
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

int GetLargest(int[] array, int[] exceptions)
{

    int i = 0;

    while (Contains(exceptions, array[i]))
    {
        i++;
    }
    int a = array[i++];
    i = 0;
    do
    {
        if (Contains(exceptions, array[i + 1])) { i++; continue; }

        if (a < array[i + 1])
            a = array[i + 1];
        i++;
    }
    while (i != array.Length - 1);
    return a;
}

bool Contains(int[] array, int num)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] == num)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int[] Sort(int[] array)
{
    int[] finallArr = new int[array.Length];
    for (int i = array.Length; i > 0; i--)
    {
        finallArr[array.Length - i] = GetLargest(array, finallArr);
    }enter code here
    return finallArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a loop that merges and de-dups the lists and uses a binary-search approach to insert new values into the destination list.

Answer (score 0):

```
var listOne = new List<int> { 3, 4, 1, 2, 7, 6, 9, 11 };
var listTwo = new List<int> { 1, 7, 8, 3, 5, 10, 15, 12 };
var result = listOne.ToList();

foreach (var n in listTwo)
{
  if (result.IndexOf(n) == -1)
    result.Add(n);
}
```

Comment: Every IndexOf is like an inner loop, so this isn't "in one loop".

Answer (score 0):

The closest solution I see would be to allocate an array knowing that integers are **bounded** to some value.

```
int[] values = new int[ Integer.MAX ]; // initialize with 0
int size1 = list1.size();
int size2 = list2.size();

for( int pos = 0; pos < size1 + size2 ; pos++ )
{
     int val =  pos > size1 ? list2[ pos-size1 ] : list1[ pos ] ;
     values[ val ]++;
}
```

Then you can argue that you have the sorted array in a "special" form :-) To get a clean sorted array, you need to traverse the `values` array, skip all position with `0` count, and build the final list.

Comment: The question dictates *one* `for` loop.

Comment: ...and according to the other answers, it seems like it's not possible unless there are other conditions to the problem (e.g. arrays are already sorted). I've refined my answer though.

Comment: Your answer reminded me of sleepsort: http://dis.4chan.org/read/prog/1295544154 - makes me giggle every time

Answer (score 0):

This will only work for lists of integers, but happily that is what you have!

```
List<int> sortedList = new List<int>();
foreach (int x in listOne)
{
    sortedList<x> = x;
}
foreach (int x in listTwo)
{
    sortedList<x> = x;
}
```

This is using the values in each list as the index position at which to store the value. Any duplicate values will overwrite the previous entry at that index position.  It meets the requirement of only one iteration over the values.

It does of course mean that there will be 'empty' positions in the list.

I suspect the job position has been filled by now though....  :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution if the two collections are already sorted (the only scenario where the question makes sense):

```
/// <summary>
/// Efficiently merges two *sorted* collections in O(n) time, so that the result is again sorted.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This method uses <see cref="Comparer{T}.Default"/>.
/// <para/>
/// When two items compare equal, the item from <paramref name="sorted1"/>
/// is sorted before the item from <paramref name="sorted2"/>.
/// </remarks>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the items in the collections.</typeparam>
/// <param name="sorted1">The first collection.</param>
/// <param name="sorted2">The second collection.</param>
/// <returns>The merged sorted collection.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown when any argument is <c>null</c>.</exception>
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeTwoSortedCollections<T>(IEnumerable<T> sorted1, IEnumerable<T> sorted2)
{
    return MergeTwoSortedCollections<T>(sorted1, sorted2, Comparer<T>.Default.Compare);
}


/// <summary>
/// Efficiently merges two *sorted* collections in O(n) time, so that the result is again sorted.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// When <paramref name="compareItems"/> returns 0 for two items, the item from <paramref name="sorted1"/>
/// is sorted before the item from <paramref name="sorted2"/>.
/// </remarks>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the items in the collections.</typeparam>
/// <param name="sorted1">The first collection.</param>
/// <param name="sorted2">The second collection.</param>
/// <param name="compareItems">The function used to compare items.</param>
/// <returns>The merged sorted collection.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">Thrown when any argument is <c>null</c>.</exception>
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeTwoSortedCollections<T>(IEnumerable<T> sorted1, IEnumerable<T> sorted2, Comparison<T> compareItems)
{
    _ = sorted1 ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sorted1));
    _ = sorted2 ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sorted2));
    _ = compareItems ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(compareItems));

    return Core();

    IEnumerable<T> Core()
    {
        using var e1 = sorted1.GetEnumerator();
        using var e2 = sorted2.GetEnumerator();

        bool valid1 = e1.MoveNext();
        bool valid2 = e2.MoveNext();

        while (valid1 || valid2)
        {
            if (valid1 && (!valid2 || compareItems(e1.Current, e2.Current) <= 0))
            {
                yield return e1.Current;
                valid1 = e1.MoveNext();
            }
            else
            {
                yield return e2.Current;
                valid2 = e2.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).