# Most efficient algorithm for merging sorted IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, performance, algorithm, optimization

I have several huge **sorted enumerable sequences that I want to merge**. Theses lists are manipulated as `IEnumerable` but are *already sorted*. Since input lists are sorted, it should be possible to merge them in one trip, without re-sorting anything.

I would like to keep the defered execution behavior.

I tried to write a naive algorithm which do that (see below). However, it looks pretty ugly and I'm sure it can be optimized. It may exist a more academical algorithm...

```
IEnumerable<T> MergeOrderedLists<T, TOrder>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> orderedlists, 
                                            Func<T, TOrder> orderBy)
{
    var enumerators = orderedlists.ToDictionary(l => l.GetEnumerator(), l => default(T));
    IEnumerator<T> tag = null;

    var firstRun = true;
    while (true)
    {
        var toRemove = new List<IEnumerator<T>>();
        var toAdd = new List<KeyValuePair<IEnumerator<T>, T>>();
        foreach (var pair in enumerators.Where(pair => firstRun || tag == pair.Key))
        {
            if (pair.Key.MoveNext())
                toAdd.Add(pair);
            else
                toRemove.Add(pair.Key);
        }

        foreach (var enumerator in toRemove)
            enumerators.Remove(enumerator);

        foreach (var pair in toAdd)
            enumerators[pair.Key] = pair.Key.Current;

        if (enumerators.Count == 0)
            yield break;

        var min = enumerators.OrderBy(t => orderBy(t.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
        tag = min.Key;
        yield return min.Value;

        firstRun = false;
    }
}
```

The method can be used like that:

```
// Person lists are already sorted by age
MergeOrderedLists(orderedList, p => p.Age);
```

assuming the following `Person` class exists somewhere:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

Duplicates should be conserved, we don't care about their order in the new sequence. Do you see any obvious optimization I could use?

Comment: I was unhappy with the previous answers, so have a look at [my more concise solution for two collections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76363717/21984976). You can merge your _several_ lists by starting with the first and then merging the others one by one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is my fourth (thanks to @tanascius for pushing this along to something much more LINQ) cut at it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergePreserveOrder3<T, TOrder>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> aa,
    Func<T, TOrder> orderFunc)
where TOrder : IComparable<TOrder>
{
    var items = aa.Select(xx => xx.GetEnumerator()).Where(ee => ee.MoveNext())
        .OrderBy(ee => orderFunc(ee.Current)).ToList();

    while (items.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return items[0].Current;

        var next = items[0];
        items.RemoveAt(0);
        if (next.MoveNext())
        {
            // simple sorted linear insert
            var value = orderFunc(next.Current);
            var ii = 0;
            for ( ; ii < items.Count; ++ii)
            {
                if (value.CompareTo(orderFunc(items[ii].Current)) <= 0)
                {
                    items.Insert(ii, next);
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (ii == items.Count) items.Add(next);
        }
        else next.Dispose(); // woops! can't forget IDisposable
    }
}
```

Results:

```
for (int p = 0; p < people.Count; ++p)
{
    Console.WriteLine("List {0}:", p + 1);
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", String.Join(", ", people[p].Select(x => x.Name)));
}

Console.WriteLine("Merged:");
foreach (var person in people.MergePreserveOrder(pp => pp.Age))
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", person.Name);
}

List 1:
        8yo, 22yo, 47yo, 49yo
List 2:
        35yo, 47yo, 60yo
List 3:
        28yo, 55yo, 64yo
Merged:
        8yo
        22yo
        28yo
        35yo
        47yo
        47yo
        49yo
        55yo
        60yo
        64yo
```

Improved with .Net 4.0's Tuple support:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergePreserveOrder4<T, TOrder>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> aa,
    Func<T, TOrder> orderFunc) where TOrder : IComparable<TOrder>
{
    var items = aa.Select(xx => xx.GetEnumerator())
                  .Where(ee => ee.MoveNext())
                  .Select(ee => Tuple.Create(orderFunc(ee.Current), ee))
                  .OrderBy(ee => ee.Item1).ToList();

    while (items.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return items[0].Item2.Current;

        var next = items[0];
        items.RemoveAt(0);
        if (next.Item2.MoveNext())
        {
            var value = orderFunc(next.Item2.Current);
            var ii = 0;
            for (; ii < items.Count; ++ii)
            {
                if (value.CompareTo(items[ii].Item1) <= 0)
                {   // NB: using a tuple to minimize calls to orderFunc
                    items.Insert(ii, Tuple.Create(value, next.Item2));
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (ii == items.Count) items.Add(Tuple.Create(value, next.Item2));
        }
        else next.Item2.Dispose(); // woops! can't forget IDisposable
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, it is much cleaner and performs a bit better than my awful version. If you think about another version don't hesitate to update your answer. thanks!

Comment: Latest cut MergePreserveOrder2 is linear w.r.t. number of people or lists. My original and your original are both much worse in terms of growth.

Comment: Ok, I think this is the best solution according my needs. The algorithm seems to perform only necessary operations, which is probably optimal in terms of performances, and is still easy to read/understand.

Comment: Wouldn't `items.Any()` be much faster than `items.Count` in a lot of situations? It's probably a tad slower for in memory lists, but if any of the Enumerators are actually lazy loading or using `yield`, then `.Any()` should be a lot faster.

Comment: `items` is a `List<T>`, so `items.Count` will be `O(1)`.

Comment: I compared the second solution to some simpler solutions and it didn't fair all that well performance wise. Is my test too simple? https://gist.github.com/3930708 and http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2012/10/18/merge-collections-without-duplicates-in-c

Answer (score 11):

One guess I would make that might improve clarity and performance is this:

- Create a priority queue over pairs of `T`, `IEnumerable<T>` ordered according to your comparison function on `T`
- For each `IEnumerable<T>` being merged, add the item to the priority queue annotated with a reference to the `IEnumerable<T>` where it originated
- While the priority queue is not empty

  - Extract the minimum element from the priority queue
  - Advance the `IEnumerable<T>` in its annotation to the next element
  - If `MoveNext()` returned true, add the next element to the priority queue annotated with a reference to the `IEnumerable<T>` you just advanced
  - If `MoveNext()` returned false, don't add anything to the priority queue
  - Yield the dequeued element

Comment: Incidentally, this is also how you would structure a concurrent mergesort.

Comment: I have such an implementation here: http://svn.vkarlsen.no:81/public/filedetails.php?repname=LVK&path=/LVK_3_5/trunk/LVK.Core/Collections/CollectionUtils.cs, use Ctrl+F and search for MergeSorted.

Comment: Note that pretty much every usage of `IEnumerable` in this answer should actually be `IEnumerator`.  You don't advance an `IEnumerable`, you just get an `IEnumerator` out of it.  You advance an `IEnumerator`.  You also don't need to have a `Tuple<T, IEnumerator<T>>`, you can just have an `IEnumerator<T>` and use `IEnumerator.Current` whenever you want the current item in the sequence.

Answer (score 5):

How many lists do you expect to need to merge?  It looks like your algorithm will not be efficient if you have many different lists to merge.  This line is the issue:

```
var min = enumerators.OrderBy(t => orderBy(t.Value)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This will be run once for each element in all the lists, so your runtime will be O(n * m), where n is the TOTAL number of elements in all the lists, and n is the number of lists.  Expressed in terms of the average length of a list in the list of lists, the runtime is O(a * m^2).

If you are going to need to merge a lot of lists, I would suggest using a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)).  Then each iteration you can remove the smallest value from the heap, and add the next element to the heap from the list that the smallest value came from.

Comment: That's a good observation. But I would say that lists to merge are likely to be 2 - 10 at most.

Comment: +1, assuming you mean a heap as a priority queue implementation

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution with NO SORTING ... just the minimum number of comparisons.  (I omitted the actual order func passing for simplicity).  Updated to build a balanced tree:-

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Merge a pair of ordered lists
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<T> aList, IEnumerable<T> bList)
        where T:IComparable<T>
    {
        var a = aList.GetEnumerator();
        bool aOK = a.MoveNext();

        foreach (var b in bList)
        {
            while (aOK && a.Current.CompareTo(b) <= 0) {yield return a.Current; aOK = a.MoveNext();}
            yield return b;
        }
        // And anything left in a
        while (aOK) { yield return a.Current; aOK = a.MoveNext(); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Merge lots of sorted lists
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> listOfLists)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        int n = listOfLists.Count();
        if (n < 2) 
            return listOfLists.FirstOrDefault();
        else
            return Merge (Merge(listOfLists.Take(n/2)), Merge(listOfLists.Skip(n/2)));
    }


public static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var sample = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select((i) => Enumerable.Range(i, i+5).Select(j => string.Format("Test {0:00}", j)));

    Console.WriteLine("Merged:");
    foreach (var result in Merge(sample))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", result);
    }
```

Comment: listOfLists.FirstOrDefault() <- the elements of this list will be enumerated m times, where m is the number of lists to be merged. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Comment: This is a very clever solution ... and it is fast for a small amount of lists, too. @Craig: It deserves more than a simple "This is how I would have done it". But for lots of lists it will perform poor.

Comment: What did you want me to say?  He proposed a solution that looked very similar to mine.  Therefore, I didn't post the same thing twice.  sure, in the Merge listOfLists routine, continually building another enumerable would probably be faster, but how many lists are we talking about here really?  Premature optimization may be a problem.  This is a dead simple solution that is lazy enumerated and solves the problem.

Comment: @tanscius - take another look with improved balanced tree approach.

Comment: It doesn't compile anymore ^^ No overload of Merge() takes two IEnumerables. But I guess that this wouldn't help anyfurther - the problem with your approach is, that the comparison between the elements of the different lists is a big overhead (see Daniel's answer). But again, this happens only for a large amount of lists (2-5 certainly won't be an issue).

Comment: You should call Dispose() on your enumerators

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that has very good complexity analysis and that is considerably shorter than the other solutions proposed.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> self) 
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    var es = self.Select(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Where(e => e.MoveNext());
    var tmp = es.ToDictionary(e => e.Current);
    var dict = new SortedDictionary<T, IEnumerator<T>>(tmp);
    while (dict.Count > 0)
    {
        var key = dict.Keys.First();
        var cur = dict[key];
        dict.Remove(key);
        yield return cur.Current;
        if (cur.MoveNext())
            dict.Add(cur.Current, cur);                    
    }
}
```

Comment: also looks like its memory usage would be very modest

Comment: This implementation will fail if two elements that compare as equal are contained in two different sequences. (Either at es.ToDictionary or dict.Add). If that's a possibility, you need to use a real priority queue.

Comment: You should call Dispose() on your enumerators

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:
The algorithm takes the **first element of each list** and puts them within a small helper class (a sorted list that accepts mutliple elements with the same value). This sorted list uses a **binary insert**.
So the first element in this list is the element we want to return next. After doing so we remove it from the sorted list and insert the next element from its original source list (at least as long as this list contains any more elements). Again, we can **return the first element** of our sorted list. When the sorted list is empty once, we used all element from all different source lists and are done.

This solution uses less `foreach` statements and no `OrderBy` in each step - which should improve the runtime behaviour. Only the binary insert has to be done again and again.

```
IEnumerable<T> MergeOrderedLists<T, TOrder>( IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> orderedlists, Func<T, TOrder> orderBy )
{
    // Get an enumerator for each list, create a sortedList
    var enumerators = orderedlists.Select( enumerable => enumerable.GetEnumerator() );
    var sortedEnumerators = new SortedListAllowingDoublets<TOrder, IEnumerator<T>>();

    // Point each enumerator onto the first element
    foreach( var enumerator in enumerators )
    {
        // Missing: assert true as the return value
        enumerator.MoveNext();

        //  Initially add the first value
        sortedEnumerators.AddSorted( orderBy( enumerator.Current ), enumerator );
    }

    // Continue as long as we have elements to return
    while( sortedEnumerators.Count != 0 )
    {
        // The first element of the sortedEnumerator list always
        // holds the next element to return
        var enumerator = sortedEnumerators[0].Value;

        // Return this enumerators current value
        yield return enumerator.Current;

        // Remove the element we just returned
        sortedEnumerators.RemoveAt( 0 );

        // Check if there is another element in the list of the enumerator
        if( enumerator.MoveNext() )
        {
            // Ok, so add it to the sorted list
            sortedEnumerators.AddSorted( orderBy( enumerator.Current ), enumerator );
        }
    }
```

My helper class (using a simple binary insert):

```
private class SortedListAllowingDoublets<TOrder, T> : Collection<KeyValuePair<TOrder, T>> where T : IEnumerator
{
    public void AddSorted( TOrder value, T enumerator )
    {
        Insert( GetSortedIndex( value, 0, Count - 1 ), new KeyValuePair<TOrder, T>( value, enumerator ) );
    }

    private int GetSortedIndex( TOrder item, int startIndex, int endIndex )
    {
        if( startIndex > endIndex )
        {
            return startIndex;
        }
        var midIndex = startIndex + ( endIndex - startIndex ) / 2;
        return Comparer<TOrder>.Default.Compare( this[midIndex].Key, item ) < 0 ? GetSortedIndex( item, midIndex + 1, endIndex ) : GetSortedIndex( item, startIndex, midIndex - 1 );
    }
}
```

What's not implemented right now: check for an empty list, which will cause problems.
And the `SortedListAllowingDoublets` class could be improved to take a comparer instead of using the `Comparer<TOrder>.Default` on its own.

Comment: This is at least an order more elegant than mine. I like it.

Comment: Have you tried using a linked list instead of a Collection? It seems like it could be faster.

Comment: @Gabe: No, I didn't try a linked list. This answer is a solution I just coded for the OP - I didn't use a profiler, too. But I am very optimistic, that it is a fast algorithm (which however can be improved further ^^)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Linq friendly solution based on the [Wintellect's OrderedBag](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/PowerCollections/blob/master/Source/PowerCollections/OrderedBag.cs):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeOrderedLists<T, TOrder>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> orderedLists, Func<T, TOrder> orderBy)
    where TOrder : IComparable<TOrder>
{
    var enumerators = new OrderedBag<IEnumerator<T>>(orderedLists
        .Select(enumerable => enumerable.GetEnumerator())
        .Where(enumerator => enumerator.MoveNext()),
        (x, y) => orderBy(x.Current).CompareTo(orderBy(y.Current)));
    while (enumerators.Count > 0)
    {
        IEnumerator<T> minEnumerator = enumerators.RemoveFirst();
        T minValue = minEnumerator.Current;
        if (minEnumerator.MoveNext())
            enumerators.Add(minEnumerator);
        else
            minEnumerator.Dispose();
        yield return minValue;
    }
}
```

If you use any Enumerator based solution, **don't forget** to call *Dispose()*

And here is a simple test:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldMergeInOrderMultipleOrderedListWithDuplicateValues()
{
    // given
    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> orderedLists = new[]
    {
        new [] {1, 5, 7},
        new [] {1, 2, 4, 6, 7}
    };

    // test
    IEnumerable<int> merged = orderedLists.MergeOrderedLists(i => i);

    // expect
    merged.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(new [] { 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7 });
}
```

Comment: Drawback: OrderedBag doesn't have MIT license

Comment: It has [Eclipse Public License 1.0](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/PowerCollections/blob/master/License.txt)

Answer (score 1):

My version of sixlettervariables's answer.  I reduced the number of calls to orderFunc (each element only passes through orderFunc once), and in the case of ties, sorting is skipped.  This is optimized for small numbers of sources, larger numbers of elements within each source and possibly an expensive orderFunc.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergePreserveOrder<T, TOrder>(
  this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sources, 
  Func<T, TOrder> orderFunc)  
  where TOrder : IComparable<TOrder> 
{
  Dictionary<TOrder, List<IEnumerable<T>>> keyedSources =
    sources.Select(source => source.GetEnumerator())
      .Where(e => e.MoveNext())
      .GroupBy(e => orderFunc(e.Current))
      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList()); 

  while (keyedSources.Any())
  {
     //this is the expensive line
    KeyValuePair<TOrder, List<IEnumerable<T>>> firstPair = keyedSources
      .OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).First();

    keyedSources.Remove(firstPair.Key);
    foreach(IEnumerable<T> e in firstPair.Value)
    {
      yield return e.Current;
      if (e.MoveNext())
      {
        TOrder newKey = orderFunc(e.Current);
        if (!keyedSources.ContainsKey(newKey))
        {
          keyedSources[newKey] = new List<IEnumerable<T>>() {e};
        }
        else
        {
          keyedSources[newKey].Add(e);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm betting this could be further improved by a SortedDictionary, but am not brave enough to try a solution using one without an editor.

Comment: You use a Dictionary/List combination to sort the elements - I am not sure about creating a own `List` for each value. The OP says that he wants to sort large lists - so the initialization of so many lists could be a problem. I had a solution using a `SortedDictionary`, but the key has to be unique - so the value needs to be a collection again. That's why I decided to use a single list which is able to contain multiple keys (and uses a fast binary search)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modern implementation that is based on the new and powerful [`PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2) class (.NET 6). It combines the low overhead of [user7116's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2767338/11178549), with the O(log n) complexity of [tanascius's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2767259/11178549) (where N is the number of sources). It outperforms most of the other implementations presented in this question (I didn't measure them all), either slightly for small N, or massively for large N.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> MergeSorted<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> sortedSources,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IComparer<TKey> comparer = default)
{
    List<IEnumerator<TSource>> enumerators = new();
    try
    {
        foreach (var source in sortedSources)
            enumerators.Add(source.GetEnumerator());
        var queue = new PriorityQueue<IEnumerator<TSource>, TKey>(comparer);
        foreach (var enumerator in enumerators)
        {
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                queue.Enqueue(enumerator, keySelector(enumerator.Current));
        }
        while (queue.TryPeek(out var enumerator, out _))
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;
            if (enumerator.MoveNext())
                queue.EnqueueDequeue(enumerator, keySelector(enumerator.Current));
            else
                queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var enumerator in enumerators) enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In order to keep the code simple, all enumerators are disposed at the end of the combined enumeration. A more sophisticated implementation would dispose each enumerator immediately after its completion.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a terribly useful function to have around so i decided to take a stab at it.  My approach is a lot like heightechrider in that it breaks the problem down into merging two sorted IEnumerables into one, then taking that one and merging it with the next in the list.  There is most likely some optimization you can do but it works with my simple testcase:

```
      public static IEnumerable<T> mergeSortedEnumerables<T>(
            this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> listOfLists, 
            Func<T, T, Boolean> func)
      {
            IEnumerable<T> l1 = new List<T>{};
            foreach (var l in listOfLists)
            {
                 l1 = l1.mergeTwoSorted(l, func);
            }

            foreach (var t in l1)
            {
                 yield return t;
            }
      }

      public static IEnumerable<T> mergeTwoSorted<T>(
            this IEnumerable<T> l1, 
            IEnumerable<T> l2, 
            Func<T, T, Boolean> func)
      {
            using (var enumerator1 = l1.GetEnumerator())
            using (var enumerator2 = l2.GetEnumerator())
            {
                 bool enum1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
                 bool enum2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
                 while (enum1 || enum2)
                 {
                      T t1 = enumerator1.Current;
                      T t2 = enumerator2.Current;

                      //if they are both false
                      if (!enum1 && !enum2)
                      {
                            break;
                      }
                      //if enum1 is false
                      else if (!enum1)
                      {
                            enum2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
                            yield return t2;

                      }
                      //if enum2 is false
                      else if (!enum2)
                      {
                            enum1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
                            yield return t1;

                      }
                      //they are both true
                      else
                      {
                            //if func returns true then t1 < t2
                            if (func(t1, t2))
                            {
                                 enum1 = enumerator1.MoveNext();
                                 yield return t1;

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 enum2 = enumerator2.MoveNext();
                                 yield return t2;

                            }
                      }
                 }
            }
      }
```

Then to test it:

```
                List<int> ws = new List<int>() { 1, 8, 9, 16, 17, 21 };
                List<int> xs = new List<int>() { 2, 7, 10, 15, 18 };
                List<int> ys = new List<int>() { 3, 6, 11, 14 };
                List<int> zs = new List<int>() { 4, 5, 12, 13, 19, 20 };
                List<IEnumerable<int>> lss = new List<IEnumerable<int>> { ws, xs, ys, zs };

                foreach (var v in lss.mergeSortedEnumerables(compareInts))
                {
                     Console.WriteLine(v);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was asked this question as an interview question this evening and did not have a great answer in the 20 or so minutes allotted. So I forced myself to write an algorithm without doing any searches. The constraint was that the inputs were already sorted. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Merger
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int[] a = { 1, 3, 6, 102, 105, 230 };
      int[] b = { 101, 103, 112, 155, 231 };

      var mm = new MergeMania();

      foreach(var val in mm.Merge<int>(a, b))
      {
        Console.WriteLine(val);
      }
      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }

  public class MergeMania
  {
    public IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(params IEnumerable<T>[] sortedSources) 
      where T : IComparable
    {
      if (sortedSources == null || sortedSources.Length == 0) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("sortedSources");

      //1. fetch enumerators for each sourc
      var enums = (from n in sortedSources 
             select n.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();

      //2. fetch enumerators that have at least one value
      var enumsWithValues = (from n in enums 
                   where n.MoveNext() 
                   select n).ToArray();
      if (enumsWithValues.Length == 0) yield break; //nothing to iterate over

      //3. sort by current value in List<IEnumerator<T>>
      var enumsByCurrent = (from n in enumsWithValues 
                  orderby n.Current 
                  select n).ToList();
      //4. loop through
      while (true)
      {
        //yield up the lowest value
        yield return enumsByCurrent[0].Current;

        //move the pointer on the enumerator with that lowest value
        if (!enumsByCurrent[0].MoveNext())
        {
          //remove the first item in the list
          enumsByCurrent.RemoveAt(0);

          //check for empty
          if (enumsByCurrent.Count == 0) break; //we're done
        }
        enumsByCurrent = enumsByCurrent.OrderBy(x => x.Current).ToList();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to improve on @cdiggins's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14444706/129073).
This implementation works correctly if two elements that compare as equal are contained in two different sequences (i. e. doesn't have the flaw mentioned by @ChadHenderson).

The algorithm is described [in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm), the complexity is O(*m* log *n*), where *n* is the number of lists being merged and *m* is the sum of the lengths of the lists.

The `OrderedBag<T>` from [Wintellect.PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/) is used instead of a heap-based priority queue, but it doesn't change the complexity.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(
   IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> listOfLists,
   Func<T, T, int> comparison = null)
{
   IComparer<T> cmp = comparison != null
      ? Comparer<T>.Create(new Comparison<T>(comparison))
      : Comparer<T>.Default;
   List<IEnumerator<T>> es = listOfLists
      .Select(l => l.GetEnumerator())
      .Where(e => e.MoveNext())
      .ToList();
   var bag = new OrderedBag<IEnumerator<T>>(
      (e1, e2) => cmp.Compare(e1.Current, e2.Current));
   es.ForEach(e => bag.Add(e));
   while (bag.Count > 0)
   {
      IEnumerator<T> e = bag.RemoveFirst();
      yield return e.Current;
      if (e.MoveNext())
      {
         bag.Add(e);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please don't forget to call Dispose() on your enumerators

Answer (score 0):

Each list being merged should be already sorted. This method will locate the equal elements with respect to the order of their lists. For example, if elements Ti == Tj, and they are respectively from list i and list j (i < j), then Ti will be in front of Tj in the merged result.
The complexity is O(mn), where n is the number of lists being merged and m is the sum of the lengths of the lists.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T, TOrder>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> TEnumerable_2, Func<T, TOrder> orderFunc, IComparer<TOrder> cmp=null)
{
    if (cmp == null)
    {
        cmp = Comparer<TOrder>.Default;
    }

    List<IEnumerator<T>> TEnumeratorLt = TEnumerable_2
       .Select(l => l.GetEnumerator())
       .Where(e => e.MoveNext())
       .ToList();

    while (TEnumeratorLt.Count > 0)
    {
        int intMinIndex;
        IEnumerator<T> TSmallest = TEnumeratorLt.GetMin(TElement => orderFunc(TElement.Current), out intMinIndex, cmp);
        yield return TSmallest.Current;

        if (TSmallest.MoveNext() == false)
        {
            TEnumeratorLt.RemoveAt(intMinIndex);
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the first min item in an IEnumerable, and return the index of it by minIndex
/// </summary>
public static T GetMin<T, TOrder>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, TOrder> orderFunc, out int minIndex, IComparer<TOrder> cmp = null)
{
    if (self == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("self");            

    IEnumerator<T> selfEnumerator = self.GetEnumerator();
    if (!selfEnumerator.MoveNext()) throw new ArgumentException("List is empty.", "self");

    if (cmp == null) cmp = Comparer<TOrder>.Default;

    T min = selfEnumerator.Current;
    minIndex = 0;
    int intCount = 1;
    while (selfEnumerator.MoveNext ())
    {
        if (cmp.Compare(orderFunc(selfEnumerator.Current), orderFunc(min)) < 0)
        {
            min = selfEnumerator.Current;
            minIndex = intCount;
        }
        intCount++;
    }

    return min;
}
```

Comment: Remove 4 spaces from all lines: Select all the code and press the `{}` button. It's a toggle you see.

Answer (score 0):

I've took a more functional approach, hope this reads well.

First of all here is the merge method itself:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeSorted<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> xss) where T :IComparable
{
    var stacks = xss.Select(xs => new EnumerableStack<T>(xs)).ToList();

    while (true)
    {
        if (stacks.All(x => x.IsEmpty)) yield break;

        yield return 
            stacks
                .Where(x => !x.IsEmpty)
                .Select(x => new { peek = x.Peek(), x })
                .MinBy(x => x.peek)
                .x.Pop();
    }
}
```

The idea is that we turn each `IEnumerable` into `EnumerableStack` that has `Peek()`, `Pop()` and `IsEmpty` members.

It works just like a regular stack. Note that calling `IsEmpty` might enumerate wrapped `IEnumerable`.

Here is the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Wraps IEnumerable in Stack like wrapper
/// </summary>
public class EnumerableStack<T>
{
    private enum StackState
    {
        Pending,
        HasItem,
        Empty
    }

    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;

    private StackState _state = StackState.Pending;

    public EnumerableStack(IEnumerable<T> xs)
    {
        _enumerator = xs.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        var res = Peek(isEmptyMessage: "Cannot Pop from empty EnumerableStack");
        _state = StackState.Pending;
        return res;
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        return Peek(isEmptyMessage: "Cannot Peek from empty EnumerableStack");
    }

    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get
        {
            if (_state == StackState.Empty) return true;
            if (_state == StackState.HasItem) return false;
            ReadNext();
            return _state == StackState.Empty;
        }
    }

    private T Peek(string isEmptyMessage)
    {
        if (_state != StackState.HasItem)
        {
            if (_state == StackState.Empty) throw new InvalidOperationException(isEmptyMessage);
            ReadNext();
            if (_state == StackState.Empty) throw new InvalidOperationException(isEmptyMessage);
        }
        return _enumerator.Current;
    }

    private void ReadNext()
    {
        _state = _enumerator.MoveNext() ? StackState.HasItem : StackState.Empty;
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the MinBy extension method in case haven't written one on your own already:

```
public static T MinBy<T, TS>(this IEnumerable<T> xs, Func<T, TS> selector) where TS : IComparable
{
    var en = xs.GetEnumerator();
    if (!en.MoveNext()) throw new Exception();

    T max = en.Current;
    TS maxVal = selector(max);
    while(en.MoveNext())
    {
        var x = en.Current;
        var val = selector(x);
        if (val.CompareTo(maxVal) < 0)
        {
            max = x;
            maxVal = val;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Person
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public int Age
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Person[] persons1 = new Person[] { new Person() { Name = "Ahmed", Age = 20 }, new Person() { Name = "Ali", Age = 40 } };
            Person[] persons2 = new Person[] { new Person() { Name = "Zaid", Age = 21 }, new Person() { Name = "Hussain", Age = 22 } };
            Person[] persons3 = new Person[] { new Person() { Name = "Linda", Age = 19 }, new Person() { Name = "Souad", Age = 60 } };

            Person[][] personArrays = new Person[][] { persons1, persons2, persons3 };

            foreach(Person person in MergeOrderedLists<Person, int>(personArrays, person => person.Age))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", person.Name, person.Age);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static IEnumerable<T> MergeOrderedLists<T, TOrder>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> orderedlists, Func<T, TOrder> orderBy)
        {
            List<IEnumerator<T>> enumeratorsWithData = orderedlists.Select(enumerable => enumerable.GetEnumerator())
                                                                   .Where(enumerator => enumerator.MoveNext()).ToList();

            while (enumeratorsWithData.Count > 0)
            {
                IEnumerator<T> minEnumerator = enumeratorsWithData[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < enumeratorsWithData.Count; i++)
                    if (((IComparable<TOrder>)orderBy(minEnumerator.Current)).CompareTo(orderBy(enumeratorsWithData[i].Current)) >= 0)
                        minEnumerator = enumeratorsWithData[i];

                yield return minEnumerator.Current;

                if (!minEnumerator.MoveNext())
                    enumeratorsWithData.Remove(minEnumerator);
            }             
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm suspicious LINQ is smart enough to take advantage of the prior existing sort order:

```
IEnumerable<string> BiggerSortedList =  BigListOne.Union(BigListTwo).OrderBy(s => s);
```

Comment: On any `IEnumerable` in general? I doubt it.

Comment: Does Union preserve duplicates, though?  I know UNION in SQL doesn't.

Comment: It seems impossible to know that. Using OrderBy performs a sort that consumes all the memory -- something I would like to avoid

Comment: @mgroves, Union is deferred and causes no dupes.

Comment: Use Concat instead of Union to preserve all elements of the sources.  Also - This is a full re-ordering and does not take advantage of the pre-sorting.

Comment: If Union *doesn't* preserve dupes, then that *won't* work for franck, right?