# Is there an easy way to merge two ordered sequences using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

Given

```
IEnumerable<T> first;
IEnumerable<T> second;
```

and that both `first` and `second` are ordered by a comparer `Func<T, T, int>` that returns 0 for equality, -1 when the first is "smaller" and 1 when the second is "smaller".

**Is there a straight-forward way using LINQ to merge the two sequences in a way that makes the resulting sequence also ordered by the same comparer?**

We're currently using a hand-crafted algorithm that works, but the readability of a straight-forward LINQ statement would be preferable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most efficient algorithm for merging sorted IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2767007/most-efficient-algorithm-for-merging-sorted-ienumerablet)

Comment: Have you extracted your hand-crafted algorithm into a separate method?  That would be the simplest way to improve readability.

Comment: If you like readability (over performance) then: `var both = first.Union(second).OrderBy(comparer);`

Comment: @Jon: I already know about that "the most efficient algorithm" thread. Was just hoping that LINQ would help with readability. :)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: That method will discard duplicates (probably not desired).  `var both = first.Concat(second).OrderBy(comparer);` is probably what you want.

Comment: @JohannGerell: Sure, that was not my point. The point was to show you that such a method has already been written, so you can copy/paste the extension method and go. Also, to prevent people from scattering identical answers across separate questions.

Comment: The problem here is that, even though there is an IOrderedEnumerable interface defined in System.Linq, it doesn't expose the IComparer   used to sort the the two Enumerables. without being able to compare the IComparers (and their settings), you can't assume both Enumerables are in the same order. Which is probably why things are the way they are. `.Concat/.Union` followed by `.OrderBy/.OrderByDescending` is the best Linq can give you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14444706/184528

Comment: I was not happy with the previous answers, so I posted mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76363717/21984976).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could define an extension method for this. Something like

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MergeSorted<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, Func<T, T, int> comparer) 
{
    using (var firstEnumerator = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var secondEnumerator = second.GetEnumerator())
    {

        var elementsLeftInFirst = firstEnumerator.MoveNext();
        var elementsLeftInSecond = secondEnumerator.MoveNext();
        while (elementsLeftInFirst || elementsLeftInSecond)
        {
            if (!elementsLeftInFirst)
            {
                    do
                    {
                        yield return secondEnumerator.Current;
                    } while (secondEnumerator.MoveNext());
                    yield break;
            }

            if (!elementsLeftInSecond)
            {
                    do
                    {
                        yield return firstEnumerator.Current;
                    } while (firstEnumerator.MoveNext());
                    yield break;
            }

            if (comparer(firstEnumerator.Current, secondEnumerator.Current) < 0)
            {
                yield return firstEnumerator.Current;
                elementsLeftInFirst = firstEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }
            else
            {
                yield return secondEnumerator.Current;
                elementsLeftInSecond = secondEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var s1 = new[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
var s2 = new[] { 2, 4, 6, 6, 6, 8 };

var merged = s1.MergeSorted(s2, (a, b) => a > b ? 1 : -1).ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", merged));
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: Parameter `comparer` could be allowed to be null (optional parameter) and set to `Comparer<T>.Default.Compare` if it is null.

Answer (score 0):

I think, converting the first enumerable to list and adding second item to this list then calling sort will do the trick.

```
        IEnumerable<int> first = new List<int>(){1,3};
        IEnumerable<int> second = new List<int>(){2,4};

        var temp = first.ToList();
        temp.AddRange(second);


        temp.Sort(new Comparison<int>(comparer)); // where comparer is Func<T,T,int>
```

Comment: This implementation is O(n) in extra storage, O(n lg n) in time typical case and O(n^2) in time worst case. There is an algorithm which is both O(1) in extra storage and O(n) in time.